# turtlebot simulator for fuerte

Tags: simulation, turtlebot, ros-fuerte

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a newly-acquired turtlebot.  I have installed ROS fuerte on the turtlebot netbook and an ubuntu base computer, both running Ubuntu 10.04.  All has been going well so far with the actual robot. I would like to experiment with the turtlebot simulator, as well, but the installation instructions are all for ROS electric.  Is there a working simulator version for fuerte yet?

Thanks!

Susan Fox

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/36371/turtlebot-simulator-for-fuerte/) by [Susan Eileen Fox](https://answers.ros.org/users/2507/susan-eileen-fox/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-06-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

yes there is a working simulator for fuerte you should be able to use all the same commands. I've filed a ticket to get those instructions updated here: http://kforge.ros.org/turtlebot/trac/ticket/145

---

Originally posted by [mmwise](https://answers.ros.org/users/2/mmwise/) with karma: 8372 on 2012-06-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1